# tikzpicture in the background of text that is typeset in non-restricted horizontal mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, atbegshi

I'd like to get a tikzpicture into the background of text that is typeset by LaTeX in non-restricted horizontal mode.

Currently I do such things by means of the atbegshi-package.

Something similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\colorlet{MYcolor}{green}%

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\noindent\lower-\ht\strutbox\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \coordinate (begin the line) at (0,0) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\lipsum[1]\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate (end the line) at (0,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox {%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[solid, MYcolor,line width=1cm ,opacity=1] (begin the line) -- (end the line);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

I said "something similar" because the code used in real-life is more complex as you need to take into account the temporal asynchrony of the output-routine due to which it is not ensured that the minipage in question will end up on the page which is shipped out as the next one.

My question is:

Are there less cumbersome ways of getting entire tikzpictures into the background of text that is typeset by LaTeX in non-restricted horizontal mode?

Can you do that without atbegshi **and** without measuring boxes **and** with leaving typesetting paragraphs to LaTeX's non-restricted horizontal mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the question

> Can you do that without atbegshi and without measuring boxes and with
>   leaving typesetting paragraphs to LaTeX's non-restricted horizontal
>   mode?

translates into

> Can one do away with the freaking `\hfill`?

the answer is

> Yes, of course.

With `tikzmark` you can even add sanity checks via `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\colorlet{MYcolor}{green}%

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\tikzmark{start}
\lipsum[1]\tikzmark{end}
\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{after}%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox {%
    \hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \path (pic cs:after) coordinate (aux1)
     (pic cs:end) coordinate (aux2);
    \draw[solid, MYcolor,line width=1cm ,opacity=1]
     (pic cs:start) -- (aux1|-aux2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
  }%
 \fi
}%
\end{minipage}\tikzmark{after}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But the freaking  `\hfill` does not seem as freaking to me as the `\AtBeginShipoutNext`-thingie. Because with `\AtBeginShipoutNext` you need to trace whether the text with the background-image really goes on the page produced by the next `\shipout`... This is feasible, e.g., using zref's abspage-module for storing absolute page-numbers, and creating another `\label`-`\ref`-like-mechanism for referencing coordinates on the right pages, but it is, eh, freaking... ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez This can be all taken care of with ` \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{after}`. You can just add this to the an "unrestricted" ship out (I do not know the command because I usually use `eso-pic`, of course this builds on `atbegshi` but the macros are easier to remember) and the  ` \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{after}` will make sure it only does its work on the relevant page.

Comment: It is still not clear to me how `\AtBeginShipoutNext` "gets to know" whether the minipage in question and the `\tikzmark` named `after` end up on the page produced by the `\shipout` in question. In case these things do not fit on that page it might happen that they do not end up on that page but on the next page (which will not be produced by that `\shipout` but by another `\shipout` where the directives of this `\AtBeginShipoutNext` do not apply any more...).

Comment: @UlrichDiez This is all true, and can be solved with more elaborate tests, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534205.

Comment: I am stupid: Instead of `\AtBeginShipoutNext` I can just use `\AtBeginShipout` which will be carried out with every shipout. As long as there is only one `\tikzmark` named `after`, the `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage`-condition will be true with exactly one of the `\shipout`s... Thank you very much. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, that's what I meant. I just did not know the name of the macro in `atbegshi`. In the other answer I've done precisely that in the `eso-pic` syntax. Note also that you can have annotations that run over more than one pages that way.