# Returning TikZ arrow across multiple pages

Tags: marginnote, tikzmark, eso-pic, tikzpagenodes

I want to have arrows between my marginnotes and I achieved this with \tikzmarknode. I've also fixed the issue with multiple pages (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534199/draw-tikz-arrow-across-multiple-pages)).

However, when I put in a returning arrow, to showcase a loop, it does not work and I could not get it to (figure 2)

[image: Figure 1]  [image: Figure 2]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand\PageOfTikzmark[1]{%
    \csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand{\ConnectTikZmarknodes}[3][]{\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shorten >=1.5mm, 
        shorten <=1.5mm,#1]
        \iftikzmark{#2}{\edef\pageA{\PageOfTikzmark{#2}}}{\edef\pageA{-1}}% 
        \iftikzmark{#3}{\edef\pageB{\PageOfTikzmark{#3}}}{\edef\pageB{-1}}% 
        \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{#2}
        \edef\myflag{1}%
        \else
        \edef\myflag{0}%
        \fi 
        \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{#3}
        \edef\myflag{\the\numexpr\myflag+2}%
        \fi 
        \ifcase\myflag
        \or
        \draw[-] ([xshift=7pt]#2.south west)
            to ([xshift=7pt]#2.south west|-current page text area.south);
        \or
        \draw[->] ([xshift=7pt]#3.north west|-current page text area.north) 
            to ([xshift=7pt]#3.north west);  
        \or
        \draw[->] ([xshift=7pt]#2.south west)
            to ([xshift=7pt]#3.north west);
        \fi
        \ifnum\value{page}>\pageA
        \ifnum\value{page}<\pageB
        \draw ([xshift=7pt]current page text area.north east) to
        ([xshift=7pt]current page text area.south east);
        \fi
        \fi
    \end{tikzpicture}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes{1}{2}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes{2}{3}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes{3}{4}

    \lipsum[1-7]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{1}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{2}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1]  % <- doesn't work
    % \lipsum[1][1-4] % <- works
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{3}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1][1-4]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{4}{Test Test}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shorten >=1.5mm, shorten <=1.5mm]
        \draw[->,rounded corners] ([xshift=7pt]4.south west) |- ([shift={(6mm,-5mm)}]4.south east) -- ([shift={(6mm,5mm)}]2.north east) -| ([xshift=-7pt]2.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE doesn't compile for me

Comment: Well, I've copied the MWE in two different TeX editors and it compiles for both.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to draw a "loop" arrow which starts from the below of node 4, goes through right of nodes 4 to 2, and ends at the above of node 2, and you want this "loop" arrow is correctly drawn even when nodes 2 and 4 resides in different pages. Do you?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: @Johannes Sorry, it does compile. I just needed to update my distribution (last year's is too old apparently).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is that this more or less included in the answer you are linking to, which one can upgrade without losing downward compatibility. All one has to do is to make some values that were fixed in the previous code to become pgf keys. Then you can supply the `\ConnectTikZmarknodes` with some options in which you change the `to path` to fit your requirement.

In order to have some conventions, we will order the chronological nodes chronologically, i.e. the earlier node will be referred to as `start` and the later one as `target`, even though for the backwards connection the arrow head attaches then at the start node. This is why the corresponding keys have a `<-` arrow.

As in the linked answer, there are four cases:

1. None of the nodes on the current page. If the page is between these nodes, the connection will be drawn using the `between` style.
2. The first node on the current page. In this case the `from` style will be used.
3. The second node on the current page. In this case the `target` style will be used.
4. Both nodes on the same page. In this case the `same` style will be used.

We indicate which style is responsible for which situation. Each style will usually contain a `to path` key, which controls how the connection is drawn in detail. For instance,

```
from/.style={-,to path={([xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west) --
([xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west|-S)}},
```

means that we are talking about case 2. The connection will start 7pt right of the south west of anchor of the start node. It will go to `([xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west|-S)`, where the `|-` syntax in the node means "take the x coordinate of `[xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west` and the y coordinate of `S`, see e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/194703) for a discussion. The `S` node is an auxiliary node that sits below the bottom of the text area, with the distance being stored in `south margin`. Analogous statements apply to `N`, which is `north margin` above the top of the text area. The coordinate `R` is left by `right distance` of the right border of the page, and can be used to set the horizontal position of the backwards loop.

All one has to do for the backward loop is to change these styles from their initial values. The collection of styles can be stored in a style, which is called `loop up` here. Given this style, getting the loop is as simple as saying

```
\ConnectTikZmarknodes[connected tikzmarks/loop up]{2}{4}
```

Let me stress once more that even though the arrow goes from `4` to `2`, the order in which the nodes appear in the command is chronological, i.e. `2` is before `4` because this node is on an earlier page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm, marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PageOfTikzmark[1]{%
\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname}
\makeatother
\tikzset{connected tikzmarks/.cd,
indent/.initial=7pt,% distance from anchor
north margin/.initial=5mm, % distance the connections go beyond the text area at the top
south margin/.initial=5mm, % distance the connections go beyond the text area at the bottom
right distance/.initial=4mm, % distance of loop arrow from the right boundary of
% the page (not text area)
same/.style={->,to path={([xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west) --
        ([xshift=7pt]\tikztotarget.north west)}},% style for the same page
between/.style={-,to path={([xshift=20pt]current page text area.east|-N) 
    -- ([xshift=20pt]current page text area.east|-S)}},% style for the that none of the marks is on a page between them
target/.style={->,to path={([xshift=7pt]\tikztotarget.north west|-N) --
([xshift=7pt]\tikztotarget.north west)}},% style for the connection to target while from is on other page
from/.style={-,to path={([xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west) --
([xshift=7pt]\tikztostart.south west|-S)}},% style for the connection from start while from is on other page
loop up/.style={rounded corners,/tikz/connected tikzmarks/.cd,
  same/.style={<-,to path={([xshift=-7pt]\tikztostart.north east)
    |- ([yshift=5mm]\tikztostart.north-|R) --
    ([yshift=-5mm]\tikztotarget.south-|R) -|
    ([xshift=7pt]\tikztotarget.south west)}},
  from/.style={<-,to path={([xshift=-7pt]\tikztostart.north east)
    |- ([yshift=5mm]\tikztostart.north-|R) -- (S-|R)}},
  target/.style={-,to path={(N-|R) -- ([yshift=-5mm]\tikztotarget.south-|R) 
    -| ([xshift=7pt]\tikztotarget.south west)}},
  between/.style={-,to path={(N-|R) -- (S-|R)}}}
}
\newcommand{\ConnectTikZmarknodes}[3][]{\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shorten >=1.5mm, 
    shorten <=1.5mm,#1]
    \iftikzmark{#2}{\edef\pageA{\PageOfTikzmark{#2}}}{\edef\pageA{-1}}% 
    \iftikzmark{#3}{\edef\pageB{\PageOfTikzmark{#3}}}{\edef\pageB{-1}}% 
    \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{#2}
    \edef\myflag{1}%
    \else
    \edef\myflag{0}%
    \fi 
    \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{#3}
    \edef\myflag{\the\numexpr\myflag+2}%
    \fi 
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/connected tikzmarks/##1}}
    \path 
     ([yshift=-\pv{south margin}]current page text area.south) coordinate (S)
     ([yshift=\pv{north margin}]current page text area.north) coordinate (N)
     ([xshift=-\pv{right distance}]current page.east) coordinate (R)
     ;
    \ifcase\myflag
    \or
     \draw[connected tikzmarks/from] (#2) to (#3);
    \or
     \draw[connected tikzmarks/target] (#2) to (#3);  
    \or
     \draw[connected tikzmarks/same] (#2) to (#3);
    \fi
    \ifnum\value{page}>\pageA
    \ifnum\value{page}<\pageB
    \draw[connected tikzmarks/between] (#2) to (#3);
    \fi
    \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes{1}{2}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes{2}{3}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes{3}{4}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes[connected tikzmarks/loop up]{2}{4}
    \ConnectTikZmarknodes[connected tikzmarks/loop up]{5}{6}

    \lipsum[1-7]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{1}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{2}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1]  % 
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{3}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1][1-4]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{4}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1][1-8]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{5}{Test Test}}
    \lipsum[1][1-4]
    \marginnote{\tikzmarknode{6}{Test Test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works, except that the returning arrow on the last node should be in line with the previous arrows. Also, if all are on the same page, the arrows break.

Comment: @Johannes I added a version which does that and which is easier to customize.