# Tikz picture with tikzmark across page boundary won't print if inside environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, tikzmark

Combining [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483398/tikzmarknode-lines-with-hooks) solution to draw braces with `tikzmark`s, with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483547/test-if-tikzmark-exists-on-same-page) to make them go across page boundaries, presents me with an interesting problem:  It won't print the vertical part on the first page if `tikzmark` sits in an environment.
**Edit**: I'm using code from the [latest update](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/commit/1604120479f58f848d9ce9c7f869c1327c333394#diff-dde7301cf653c46f5b5cf29d3e66be13) to the tikzmark package that includes the `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage` macro, which I added below too.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{tikzmarklines}\setcounter{tikzmarklines}{0} % 

% The following code provides the iftikzmarkoncurrentpage macro
\makeatletter    
\newif\iftikzmark@
\renewcommand\iftikzmark[3]{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
      #3%
    }{%
      #2%
    }%
}%

\newcommand\iftikzmarkexists[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
    \tikzmark@false%
  }{%
    \tikzmark@true%
  }%
  \iftikzmark@
}%

\newcommand\iftikzmarkonpage[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
    \tikzmark@false
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname}{%
      \tikzmark@false
    }{%
      \ifnum\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname=#2\relax%
      \tikzmark@true
      \else
      \tikzmark@false
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \iftikzmark@
}

\newcommand\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
    \tikzmark@false
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname}{%
      \tikzmark@false
    }{%
      \ifnum\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname=\the\value{page}\relax%
      \tikzmark@true
      \else
      \tikzmark@false
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \iftikzmark@
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  next page=below,
  brace/.style n args={2}{insert path={%
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#1) -- 
  ([xshift=-0.3pt,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#1) -- 
  ([xshift=-0.3pt,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#2) -- 
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#2) -- 
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#2) --
  ([xshift=0.3pt,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#2) --
  ([xshift=0.3pt,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#1) --
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#1) --
  cycle}}}

\newif\iffirstmark

\newcommand{\linestart}{%
  \stepcounter{tikzmarklines}%
  \tikzmark{a\thetikzmarklines}%
  \firstmarktrue
  \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{b\thetikzmarklines}%
  \else
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,next page=below]%
  \clip (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
  \fill[overlay,brace={pic cs:a\thetikzmarklines}{pic cs:b\thetikzmarklines}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\linefinish}{%
  \iffirstmark
  \tikzmark{b\thetikzmarklines}%
  \firstmarkfalse
  \fi
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \clip (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
  \fill[overlay,brace={pic cs:a\thetikzmarklines}{0,0}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document} 
% This works fine:
Text \linestart text text
\newpage
Text text \linefinish text

% But not this
\begin{center} Text \linestart text text \end {center}
\newpage 
\begin{center} Text text \linefinish text \end {center}
\end{document}
```

Only the little hook is printed on the second page, but not the vertical line to page 3.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use a special version of `tikzmark`? I get an error `! Undefined control sequence.
\linestart ...stmarktrue \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage 
                                                  {b\thetikzmarklines }\else..`

Comment: @marmot Oops, yes, I do ... I used the last one from github because Andrew had recently added the `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage` command which is used here.

Comment: https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/commit/1604120479f58f848d9ce9c7f869c1327c333394#diff-dde7301cf653c46f5b5cf29d3e66be13

Comment: OK, I cannot run it but I suspect it may have not to do with the environment but with the fact that the if's get confused. That is, did you try to have the tikzmarks in the center environments first?

Comment: @marmot You mean putting the environment first?  Yes, I tried that too, but same result :(

Comment: I cannot run the file even after I downloaded the file from the repository (but most likely I am doing something dumb, I cannot extract the dtx file either). So maybe you want to report an issue at the github repository for your observation?

Comment: @marmot I added the code above, it should compile now as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the if global: `\global\firstmarktrue` and, as you pointed out, `\global\firstmarkfalse`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{tikzmarklines}\setcounter{tikzmarklines}{0} % 

% The following code provides the iftikzmarkoncurrentpage macro
\makeatletter    
\newif\iftikzmark@
\renewcommand\iftikzmark[3]{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
      #3%
    }{%
      #2%
    }%
}%

\newcommand\iftikzmarkexists[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
    \tikzmark@false%
  }{%
    \tikzmark@true%
  }%
  \iftikzmark@
}%

\newcommand\iftikzmarkonpage[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
    \tikzmark@false
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname}{%
      \tikzmark@false
    }{%
      \ifnum\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname=#2\relax%
      \tikzmark@true
      \else
      \tikzmark@false
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \iftikzmark@
}

\newcommand\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{%
    \tikzmark@false
  }{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname}{%
      \tikzmark@false
    }{%
      \ifnum\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}\endcsname\endcsname=\the\value{page}\relax%
      \tikzmark@true
      \else
      \tikzmark@false
      \fi
    }%
  }%
  \iftikzmark@
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  next page=below,
  brace/.style n args={2}{insert path={%
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#1) -- 
  ([xshift=-0.3pt,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#1) -- 
  ([xshift=-0.3pt,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#2) -- 
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#2) -- 
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#2) --
  ([xshift=0.3pt,yshift=0.1pt+.5ex]#2) --
  ([xshift=0.3pt,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#1) --
  ([xshift=0.15em,yshift=-0.1pt+.5ex]#1) --
  cycle}}}

\newif\iffirstmark

\newcommand{\linestart}{%
  \stepcounter{tikzmarklines}%
  \tikzmark{a\number\value{tikzmarklines}}%
  \global\firstmarktrue
  \iftikzmarkoncurrentpage{b\number\value{tikzmarklines}}%
  \else
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,next page=below]%
  \clip (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
  \fill[overlay,brace={pic cs:a\number\value{tikzmarklines}}{pic cs:b\number\value{tikzmarklines}}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\linefinish}{%
  \iffirstmark
  \tikzmark{b\number\value{tikzmarklines}}%
  \global\firstmarkfalse
  \fi
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \clip (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
  \fill[overlay,brace={pic cs:a\number\value{tikzmarklines}}{0,0}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document} 
% But not this
\begin{center} Text \linestart text text \end{center}
\newpage 
\begin{center} Text text \linefinish text \end{center}


% This works fine:
Text \linestart text text
\newpage
Text text \linefinish text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks so much!  Would `\firstmarkfalse` also have to be global?

Comment: @jan Yes. Good catch!