# Tikz: dimension too large error when drawing a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a mapping showing the flow of ideas in a course, something similar to [this](https://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/en/mitarbeiter/tantau/lehre/lectures/Algorithmendesign-Karte-2016.pdf)

However, whenever I try to create a long path connecting a topic with a subject, I get a "Dimension too large" error. I can't see that there's a math overflow error. It seems to be caused purely by the length of the path. In the MWE below, the troublesome line tries to connect Topic 1 to Subject 1. However, even if I try to connect Topic 1 to something further away than Section 3 (e.g. Section 2), I get the same error making me think the error has to do with the length of the path, yet I cannot see that such a restriction on path length exists in tikz.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
  
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (115,70);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,115} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\small{\x}}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,70} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\small{\y}}; }
    
        \node [anchor=west] at (1,66)  {\small{Topic 1}};
        \node [anchor=west] at (1,30)  {\small{Topic 2}};
        \draw (20,10) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 1}};
        \draw (20,30) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 2}};
        \draw (20,31) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 3}};
        \draw (20,32) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 4}};
        \draw (20,33) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 5}};
        \draw (20,35) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 6}};
        \draw (20,40) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 7}};
        \draw (20,50) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 8}};
    
        \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,50);
        \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,40);
        \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,35);
        \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,33);
        \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,32);
        \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,31);
%       \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,30);  % This line causes a "Dimensions too large" error
%       \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,10);  % This line causes a "Dimensions too large" error
        \draw (4.0,30) to [out=0, in=180] (20,10);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any help getting around this error would be greatly appreciated. I'm probably missing something really obvious.

**UPDATE**
So this is bizarre. Following a hint in an answer to this question
[Dimension too large error with too many tikz marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491381/dimension-too-large-error-with-too-many-tikzmarks), I just asked pdflatex to continue compiling the document and the paths appeared. Using the tracingmacros and tracingcommands commands I think the "Dimensions too large" error seems to have something to do with \pgf@ya but I don't have time to dig deeper.

Comment: Not related but you can shorten your code like this: `\draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,50) node [anchor=west] {\small{Section 8}};`.

Comment: Are you really trying to draw picture that is 115cm wide and 70cm tall? That's a bit large to fit on a beamer slide. The base units in TikZ are cm.

Comment: Henri, I'm using the beamerposter package for creating large figures....unless I've done something exceptionally stupid.

Comment: Just for reference, Tantau's map that I link to in the original question is 46.82 x 33.12 inches and was produced by LuaTeX (which may help solve the problem, but I've not used LuaTeX before so I'm not sure). A different, but very similar map at [this link](https://ddi.uni-wuppertal.de/website/repoLinks/v606_sose-2021-ddi-map.pdf) has the same size but was produced using pdflatex, so I'm not sure using LuaTeX is the solution.

Comment: I tested with LuaLaTeX and it produces the same error. Maybe one of the internal control points of the curved edge causes the issue. A straight line works fine. By the way: I would suggest so name your nodes and use the names for the connections. This would make the figure code much more readable.

Comment: Hi Gunter, thanks for the tips. The error appears also if I don't use beamer/beamerposter but set a page geometry of A0 and work with that. In the update I mention that if you just continue the compilation and ignore the error, the path appears properly.

Comment: @AdrianBurd, indeed despite the error message the edge is created. But thats seems reasonable as the error message also states, that it simply uses the largest value it can cope with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around this issue. Essentially you can redefine the x and y values to .5cm instead of 1cm and then scale it by a factor of 2. It is not very elegant, but compiles without errors and gives your desired output:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{} 
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm,every node/.style={font=\small}]
            \draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (115,70);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,115} {\node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x};}
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,70} {\node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y};}
            \node[anchor=east] at (4,66)  {Topic 1};
            \node[anchor=east] at (4,30)  {Topic 2};
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={anchor=west}]
                \draw (4.0,30) to [out=0, in=180] (20,10);
                \foreach \i/\j in {31/3, 32/4, 33/5, 35/6, 40/7, 50/8} {
                    \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,\i) node {Section \j};
                }
            \end{scope} 
            \begin{scope}[x=.5cm,y=.5cm,scale=2,every node/.style={anchor=west}]
                \foreach \i/\j in {10/1, 30/2} {
                    \draw (4.0,66) to [out=0, in=180] (20,\i) node {Section \j};
                }
            \end{scope} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also took the liberty of making your code a little bit shorter based on the comments above.